# How to respond_with multiple objects in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, respond-with

I have a route for example

```
POST /interaction.json
```

where the client posts a new interaction. Normally my controller would look like

```
class InteractionController < ApplicationController

    def create
        respond_with @log
    end

end
```

and I will get back a json response

```
{ "log" : { "id" : 20, .... } }
```

and the location header set to

```
http://foo.com/log/20
```

However if I wish to return more objects in my :json response than just the @log. For example to notify the client that some thing has changed with respects to this interaction the normal. Perhaps the user has won a prize for making this interaction. It would be nice to be able to do

```
response_with @log, @prize
```

and get the response

```
{ "log": { "id": 20, ... },
  "prize": { "id": 50, ...}
}
```

but that is not the way respond_with works. It treats @prize as a nested resource of @log. Can anyone suggest an idea for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Merging two independent objects is dangerous and will override any existing attributes in the caller.

Instead you could always wrap the objects and respond with the wrapper instead:

```
@response = {:log => @log, :price => @price}
respond_with @response
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `@log` and `@prize` are both hashes, you could [merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000759) both hashes and return the merge.

```
respond_with @log.merge(@prize)
```

I'm thinking it *might* overwrite the `@log.id` with `@prize.id` though. Can try something else if it does.